# How many user can access the xelatex.exe at the same time when istalled texlive on server share folder

Tags: xetex, texlive, texlive-2019, texlive-2020

We are plan to install texlive on server share folder (windows) in our institution. I have a doubt regarding How many user can access the Xelatex.exe and latex.exe at the same time for compilation
nearly 70 users can access the exe at the same time?

if users are access at the same time the compilation will be very slow?

please suggest

Comment: Are you worried about "per-seat" licensing? You have nothing to worry about. Are you worried about performance? That depends on your local network speed and latency, but you are probably fine there too.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau thanks for your confirmation, i worked before one institution, their we felt that the compilations are very slow when accessing xelatex.exe by 10 users at the same time.

Comment: It might be XeLaTeX+fontspec processing uncached fonts that gets slow even when done locally, and might get too slow done remotely. Watch out for cases where *TeX is *writing* to the remote system.

Answer (score 3):

Donald Arseneau's comment on fontspec font caching is spot-on. Add a line

```
FC_CACHEDIR = $TEXMF-VAR/fonts/cache
```

to [root]`\texmf.cnf`

For quite some time I maintained a shared TL installation for my university and wrote a launcher replacing the usual TL system integration for windows. This package is available in TL as tlaunch. Its manual also has something to say about the xetex font cache.

Comment: thaks for your help